# How to connect and login from one AWS server to another Amazon Web server from Server and do CRUD operations in the mysql installed on it?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I right now have two Amazon Web servers, say A and B. 
A has tomcat webserver and Mysql. 
B has a Mysql server too. 
People using my mobile app, which talks to server A, has to talk to server B's mysql server and do some crud operations. 
Both servers have AWS pem key security level
1) How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Few pointers to get you started in the right direction.

AWS EC2 instances will have security groups with inbound and outbound traffic restrictions. So first you need to make sure server A has outbound traffic allowed over 3306 (default port for MySQL).

As a next step, you can check security settings of server B which should allow inbound traffic from 3306. You can attach elastic IP of your server A if you are concerned about security. (You should be)

Next in the MySQL settings in server B, make sure you are not binding MySQL connection only to localhost. With these three, you should be able to come to a point where you can share error messages instead of just a question.

Comment: Thanks for answering. May I know how to "make sure you are not binding MySQL connection only to localhost." ??

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/33018/how-to-bind-to-static-ip-address-in-mysql Based on your linux dist, the location of MySQL conf varies